# How to deserialize an array using c# dynamics?

Tags: json.net

I am trying to deserialize the following JSON to an array using C# dynamics:

```
[
  {
    "itemId":"15",
    "quantity":101,
    "eventTimestamp":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "salesChannel":"1",
    "unlimitedQuantity":false
  },
  {
    "itemId":"15",
    "quantity":101,
    "eventTimestamp":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "salesChannel":"2",
    "unlimitedQuantity":false
  }
]
```

I have already tried two different approaches, without success:

```
dynamic itemsBalance = JObject.Parse(content);
```

and

```
var itemBalanceType = new {
    itemId = "", quantity = 0, eventTimestamp = "", salesChannel = ""
};
var itemsBalance = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(content, itemBalanceType);
```

I am currently using C# dynamics with all other deserializations, and would not like to create classes for each response.
Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
JArray itemsBalance = JArray.Parse(content);
if (itemsBalance != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < itemsBalance.Count; i++)
    {
        string itemBalanceJSON = itemsBalance[i].ToString();
        dynamic itemBalance = JObject.Parse(itemBalanceJSON);
        lbxResponse.Items.Add(itemBalance.itemId + " - " +    itemBalance.salesChannel +": " + itemBalance.quantity.ToString());
    }
}
```

Should there be any better, please let me know...

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with less amount of code:

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.Deserialize(content);
foreach(var entry in result)
{
  lbxResponse.Items.Add(entry.itemId + " - " + entry.salesChannel + ": " + entry.quantity);
}
```